# How Openam works with ADLDS datastore

Tags: openam, adam, adlds

I am trying to connect openam ,with ADLDS as data store using Active Director Application mode,
I had ADLDS server, running on my windows machine

what would be the LDAP bind DN: by default its shows:

CN=Administrator,CN=Users,dc=xyz,dc=zyz.

I had go through the hints given in OpenAM document. but didn't work for me

http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/admin-guide/index.html#sec-data-stores-adam

while on check of Load Schema it gives error ” Error
Unable to load schema for plug-in ADLDS for realm /. error result”

what will  be the steps to connect Openam with ADLDS data store.

Thanks,

Comment: You should enable message level debug logging and have a look at the IdRepo debug logs.

Comment: Thanks peter,  I figure out my problem, due to bind issue I had getting this error earlier, For connecting Openam with ADAM, 1first of require a proper LDAP BInd DN and password, also installed ADAM with Openam as stat installation time only.